# Passing custom Objects from applet to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, applet, classnotfoundexception, urlconnection

I have a servlet and i want to pass through `UrlConnection` some objects. When I tested it, it  worked fine.  When I passed Java native objects (`String`, `File`..). But when I try to pass my own `Object` (instance of my own Class), Object is sent into Servlet correctly via `ObjectOutputStream` but when I wanted to restore object in servlet side it doesn't work. it throws exceptions that My class was not found.

I have `MyObject` class in project with applet where is loaded and sent to servlet and then i have `MyObject` class in my servlet package too... So where I must place `MyObject` class to work it?

Here is my applet code which send `MyObject` instance to servlet via `URLConnection`

```
  URLConnection con = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outputToServlet = null;
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = null;
        MyObject my = new MyObject("200");
//open Url connection
        con = CommunicationAgent.openConnectionWithServlet(CommunicationAgent.setUrlForServletConnection());
        con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

// creating ObjectOutputStream
        try {
            outputToServlet = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

//Send MyObject instance to server      
        try {
            outputToServlet.writeObject(my);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Here is code from my servlet, easy take stream from request object and then  I want to copy incoming object to  `MyObject` instance in servlet. Here is a problem and exception is thrown

```
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        MyObject my = null;
        try {
            my = (MyObject) input.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.print("nepovedlo se precist objekt");
        }
```

Exception thrown in Tomcat

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Rozhlas_jsf] is completed
XII 04, 2012 3:43:22 DOP. Servlets.Servlet processRequest
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SoundApplet.MyObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at Servlets.Servlet.processRequest(Servlet.java:42)
    at Servlets.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and from Javaconsole

```
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/Rozhlas_jsf/Servlet with proxy=DIRECT
XII 04, 2012 3:44:26 DOP. SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion jButton8ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8084/Rozhlas_jsf/Servlet
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion.jButton8ActionPerformed(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.java:708)
    at SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion.access$1000(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.java:27)
    at SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion$12.actionPerformed(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.java:371)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion.jButton8ActionPerformed(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.java:717)
    at SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion.access$1000(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.java:27)
    at SoundApplet.SoundAppletSimpleVersion$12.actionPerformed(SoundAppletSimpleVersion.java:371)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I guess problem is in placing my classes. What I must do to work it correctly? I need Receive `MyObject` instance into servlet and then work with him in servlet. It works for native Java objects why Java cant find `MyObject` class in `SoundApplet.MyObject`.

How Java work with classes in this case. When sending FIle object for example, when I receive it in  servlet Java use Which class for it. `File` Class from libraries in my Applet or `File` class from libraries in projectwith servlet or it doesnt matter? I am really confused in this questions please try to explain me it and help.

here is image that MyObject class is really placed in compiled SoundApplet.jar in web project..
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [The Apache Tomcat 5.5 Servlet/JSP Container: Quick Start](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

> - ..
> - For classes and resources that must be shared across all web applications, place unpacked classes and resources under `$CATALINA_BASE/shared/classes`, or place JAR files containing those classes and resources under `$CATALINA_BASE/shared/lib`.

So if `SoundApplet.MyObject` is in a Jar (which I recommend), place it in the `lib` directory.
If it is not in a Jar, place the class file in the `classes/SoundApplet` directory.  As an aside, package names should be `alllowercase`, e.g.  `soundapplet`.

Also note that the class needs to be in at least **2 separate locations** to be used by both the servlet and applet.  The server class-path is outlined above, but applets (or rather the JVM) cannot access either of those paths.

Comment: i added my SoundApplet.jar to /WEB-INF/lib/SoundApplet.jar of my web application and I get this exception from Tomcat :SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Servlet] in context with path [/Rozhlas_jsf] threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: SoundApplet.MyObject cannot be cast to Servlets.MyObject

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of the servlet & applet code).

Comment: Ok i tried do simple exaple what i want to do here you have two projects. One is Applet project and next is my web project. here is the link [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/8bngey) Can  you run it ? @AndrewThompson

Comment: I already try all folders to place my Applet.jar file but my class is not found :-(

Comment: *"Can you run it ?"*  I don't intend to try downloading 5 meg of app., building it and running it.