# Custom Object Between Servlet and Applet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, applet

i have a servlet and an applet, that share a custom Object in java:

```
public class Apartment  {
    public String id_apartment;
    public String user_owner;
    public String address;
}
```

and the servlet pass the object in this way:

```
OutputStream outstr = response.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(apartment);
oos.writeObject(apartments);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

and the applet receive it in this way:

```
InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
Apartment apart = (Apartment) inputFromServlet.readObject();
inputFromServlet.close();
instr.close();
```

but the applet give me an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlet_package.Apartment`, i have created the Apartment class both in the applet jar and in the servlet package, but doesn't work...how i can do it?

i have found this question on SO: [Passing custom Objects from applet to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695487/passing-custom-objects-from-applet-to-servlet)

but i can't understand the answer...

any help?

Comment: The definition of similarity of a class in shared mode is the class should have same code (attributes) and is in the same package. If serialization is used, it should have same version id while deserializing which was used for serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You must not create the same class, in a different package, in the servlet and in the applet. You must create a single, unique Apartment class, compile it, and have it in the classpath of the servlet, and in the classpath of the applet. The same class file must be shared by the two parties.